# TwitterKit 2.5.0 and 2.7.0 won't code sign and fail app build

Tags: ios, twitter

Having trouble figure this out.

I've tried integrating Twitter support into my app using Fabric, following the instructions on the twitter developer site.

I downloaded the Fabric OSX app and told it to install the libraries into my project. It installed `Fabric.framework`, `TwitterKit.framework` and `TwitterCore.framework`. I then added a script phase as requested to by Fabric (although I'm not sure what it does).

But when I attempt to build the app, it fails code signing `TwitterKit.framework`, saying

```
.../TwitterKit.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
```

Fabric had installed TwitterKit version 2.7.0. As part of trying to work out what to do I downloaded v2.5.0 and tried that with the same results.

If I turn off code signing for `TwitterKit.frame` I get this: **Bundle at path .../TestApp.app/Frameworks/TwitterCore.framework has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist**

I'm pretty much stuck now. I can't find anyone on the net whose had this problem and I don't know why just this one framework won't code sign.

Any ideas what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

I've now figured out there are two problems with the Twitter frameworks:

1. The **TwitterKit** framework contains an embedded resources bundle. The presence of this bundle causes code-signing to fail when the framework is added to a copy files phases with a destination of Frameworks and with Code Sign on Copy turned on. So far I've established that removing the embedded bundles from the framework resolves this problem.
2. The **TwitterCore** framework's Info.plist is missing the Executable File key which causes the app to crash when attempting to run with this framework included. Manually adding this missing key fixes the problem.

Still working out my final solution.